How to listen for the MongoDB Change Stream event using spring boot 3. Note i want to listen using imperative way instead of reactive way
I am trying to listen for the Change Stream for mongodb to a collection say UserCollection. I have tried solution available but the existing solution not working. I am using dependency: spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb having version 4.2.5. The below code is not working:
    // Select the MongoDB database
    MongoDatabase database = mongoTemplate.getDb();

    // Select the collection to query
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("UserProfile");

    // Create pipeline for operationType filter
    List<Bson> pipeline = Arrays.asList(
            Aggregates.match(
                    Filters.in(
                            "operationType",
                            Arrays.asList("insert", "update", "delete")
                    )));

    // Create the Change Stream
    ChangeStreamIterable<Document> changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline)
            .fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP);

    // Iterate over the Change Stream
    for (ChangeStreamDocument<Document> changeEvent : changeStream) {
        // Process the change event here
        switch (changeEvent.getOperationType()) {
            case INSERT:
                System.out.println("MongoDB Change Stream detected an insert");
                break;
            case UPDATE:
                System.out.println("MongoDB Change Stream detected an update");
                break;
            case DELETE:
                System.out.println("MongoDB Change Stream detected a delete");
                break;
        }
    }

